# What is the encoding of Chinese characters on Wikipedia?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, cjk, url-encoding

I was looking at the encoding of Chinese characters on Wikipedia and I'm having trouble figuring out what they are using. For instance "的" is encoded as "%E7%9A%84" ([see here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/%E7%9A%84-order.gif/24px-%E7%9A%84-order.gif)). That's three bytes, however none of the encodings described [on this page](http://www.khngai.com/chinese/charmap/) uses three bytes to represent Chinese characters. UTF-8 for instance uses 2 bytes.

I'm basically trying to match these three bytes to an actual character. Any suggestion on what encoding it could be?

Comment: The UTF-8 encoding of that character is `E7 9A 84`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
>>> c='\xe7\x9a\x84'.decode('utf8')
>>> c
u'\u7684'
>>> print c
的
```

---

though Unicode encodes it in 16 bits, utf8 breaks it down to 3 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed UTF-8 was using the same encoding as unicode. That makes sense now.

Comment: @Laurent: No, because (please repeate after me) *Unicode is not an encoding*. Unicode is a standard for representing text, and encoding (actually, several encodings) is part of the standard.

Comment: @Laurent: You may be confused by the fact that in UTF-32 (which is one encoding) characters are in fact encoded by their codepoint number (i.e. the encoding is trivial). But there are other encodings, and UTF-32 is acutally not used very often.

Answer (score 21):

The header of a wikipedia page includes this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

So the page is UTF-8.

Comment: charset is misleading. It means "encoding" and not character sets, which are often confused together

Answer (score 7):

The example you give is an [IRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_resource_identifier).

IRIs use the UTF8 encoding. UTF8 implements unicode, and in unicode, each character has a *codepoint*, that is between 0x4E00 and 0x9FFF (2 bytes) for all chinese characters.

But UTF8 doesn't encode characters by just storing their *codepoint* (UTF32 does that). Instead, it uses a [more complex standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), that makes all chinese ideograms 2 **or 3** bytes long.