# Chinese characters displayed as question marks in mailing list?

Tags: email, mailing-list, mailman

I subscribed to a mailing list whose content is primarily Chinese. Every time I received the email, every Chinese character is replaced by `?`. I then dug into the email headers and found

```
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
```

I think this is the problem, to solve which I need to change the `charset` to one that is compatible with Chinese. But where do I change this?

I don't think I can change it on my side, as the problem appears regardless of which mail client I use. The mailing list is run on `Python mailman`.

Comment: Are you able to view correct Chinese characters in other apps/programs with your device?  I'm thinking you may be missing the fonts from your device.

Comment: @HarryPehkonen I have no problems viewing Chinese characters in other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

This is not the issue.

UTF-8 can display every character in every language. What is very probably actually happening is that the website in question is storing the data in a database which is *not* true UTF-8, such as MySQL *utf8_* collations and character sets [which are not true UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

If not a database storage issue then the issue comes from the character set used when the email is generated or the data is inserted into the email template, somewhere along the line the origin of the email is *not* UTF-8 or a corresponding full Chinese character set.

Such as :

- HTML input form not set to UTF-8 (or correct Chinese character set),
- HTML input form container webpage not set to UTF-8, HTML recieving form / code not set to UTF-8  (or correct Chinese character set),
- Emailer template generator not set to UTF-8  (or correct Chinese character set).
- Sending server otherwise not using default UTF-8 headers.

Also while you state "content is primarily Chinese" this doesn't narrow down much as there are at least five *main* Chinese written languages and a host of smaller languages using the same or very similar character sets.

You want to have the email constructed using [International Resource Identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier), using the UTF-8 encoding. UTF-8 implements unicode, and in unicode, each character has a codepoint, that is between 0x4E00 and 0x9FFF (2 bytes) for all chinese characters.

But UTF8 doesn't encode characters by just storing their codepoint (UTF32 does that). Instead, it uses a more complex standard, that makes all chinese ideograms 2 or 3 bytes long.

For reference: [Python Mailman and UTF-8 details](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-users/2008-January/059833.html) (2008 question) and a [character conversion guide](https://divideandconquer.se/2009/08/17/convert-mailman-translation-to-utf-8/) (2009). Also [this Stackoverflow anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27219366/3536236).

Comment: Thanks Martin. I am pretty positive that this is not really a database or other server problems, as I do see other users happily communicate with Chinese characters (seen as `?` to poor me). Is there any suggestion for me to fix this problem?

Comment: @SibbsGambling reading that the issue doesn't change on your end with different mail clients then that implies that the issue is much more likely to be the email encoding itself or otherwise the encoding on the sender website/data-core as referenced in my Answer. They're probably not using the correct character set (such as MySQL *`utf8_`* ) and they don't bother recieving their own emails. Is it possible to talk to their tech support?

Comment: @SibbsGambling OR you need to make a fundamental change to some setting on your system, can you share in your question more about what your system is and what sort of mail clients you've tried and tested this issue against? Cheers

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've tried web-version email in Chrome browser on a Mac and Mac's Mail application. I've also tried my Outlook App on my Android phone.